# Is There anyway i can use Dbunit with Junit5 while being in Spring 4?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

am trying to migrate from Junit4 to Junit5 knowing that am working with Spring Mvc , version 4.3.5 and i wanna know if there s someway to work with dbUnit for my class Repository

I did my research and the last version of dependency for Dbunit which is 2.7.3 uses Junit4. So i need to confirm that there is no way to use Dbunit while using Junit 5 except if i decide to migrate towards Spring 5 or Spring Boot cus i found some articles that talks about this

the header of my old version of my class test normally u dont need it to answer my question but as i cant post the question for Quality reasons here it is :

```
ContextConfiguration

@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:environnements.properties")
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
//TODO ajouter les xml des dépendances
// faire par groupes de dependances dans chaque test ?
@DatabaseSetup(value = {"/dbunit/RepositoryTyp-setup.xml", "/dbunit/RepositoryPTest-setup.xml"}, type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
public class PRepositoryTest extends SpringDbBasedTest {
```